# Image map hotspot not working properly in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, imagemap

[http://www.ssp-odense.dk](http://www.ssp-odense.dk/)

when you click on the area 'korup' the hotspot only registers at the top of the area. The hotspot hover function for korup should register the cursor at the bottom of the area 'Korup'. It works fine in firefox and google chrome with all the hotpot area activating the mouseover function. I dont know why it doesnt work. I have ensured to use #hashtag in the map name tag.

```
<map id="map" name="map">


 <area id="korup"  shape="poly" coords="294,146,268,147,226,130,199,113,185,127,195,149,187,159,173,
 159,154,180,145,212,132,210,123,224,127,235,114,259,114,276,115,298,99,
 315,94,331,104,342,87,353,112,341,122,342,145,333,154,331,169,337,234,339,
 271,312,242,289,233,279,247,282,258,283,249,272,249,261,258,255,262,235,264,
 228,253,220,235,218,236,213,235,204,239,187,259,176,284,176,303,166,312,156" 
 href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightkorup').style.display='block';

document.getElementById('fadekorup').style.display='block'" ;="">



 <area id="holluf" shape="poly" coords="558,453,555,436,567,437,560,365,495,374,483,
 350,445,312,496,302,524,324,535,308,561,300,572,264,608,269,634,312,649,324,658,
 343,668,341,687,348,684,370,721,390,679,446,648,440,626,451,585,444" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightholluf').style.display='block';
 document.getElementById('fadeholluf').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="soehus" shape="poly" coords="392,11,368,14,362,31,351,28,332,54,341,70,336,93,331,104,
 349,106,365,121,359,132,382,136,376,156,400,173,411,153,452,141,463,131,467,100,471,82,474,64,
 479,46,426,49,424,26,410,21,390,31,374,31,375,24,390,21" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightsoehus').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade2').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="sktklemens" shape="poly" coords="412,339,406,348,385,366,383,380,365,381,356,395,346,405,339,413,328,432,328,443,310,434,304,434,291,441,276,457,277,470,276,485,273,497,267,501,269,512,255,523,270,531,259,540,277,547,291,545,310,534,324,535,336,535,354,540,364,530,364,520,351,513,342,499,346,490,348,480,356,470,366,459,390,449,413,445,446,425,455,415,469,414,470,401,451,382,439,384,424,389,424,366,422,374,421,351" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightsktklemens').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade3').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="vestreaalykke" shape="poly" coords="272,277,274,262,317,259,328,241,341,241,342,225,357,228,365,232,376,213,369,206,380,194,391,202,397,194,389,182,398,178,400,194,399,208,417,228,419,243,430,258,419,261,418,274,408,270,409,257,397,258,377,268,367,275,360,283,348,279,339,281,328,288,315,297,308,277,297,279,289,278,280,278" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightvestreaalykke').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade5').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="seden" shape="poly" coords="587,86,603,110,598,117,610,129,631,140,636,160,635,175,623,176,614,179,602,169,598,175,564,172,562,187,574,203,582,213,593,216,594,244,598,260,566,257,544,263,526,254,527,245,531,220,522,204,514,207,506,194,505,185,503,169,496,166,483,166,470,160,465,154,464,148,464,142,480,54,489,39,502,48,492,57,485,85,490,96,483,111,472,130,489,126,516,120,526,113,541,124,554,128,562,111,581,103" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightseden').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade4').style.display='block'" ;="">


 <area id="rasmus" shape="poly" coords="153,343,238,347,283,319,320,340,367,334,375,366,316,428,293,426,254,481,225,473,219,386,193,360,168,370" target="" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightrasmus').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade610').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="naesby" shape="poly" coords="322,57,300,47,292,50,287,42,296,37,286,21,273,46,247,89,218,87,210,90,214,99,208,102,207,114,224,124,245,132,269,142,296,141,308,149,333,167,347,177,357,192,371,193,380,186,383,174,373,162,371,147,350,138,356,121,329,112,329,93,336,74" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightnaesby').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadenaesby').style.display='block'" ;="">


 <area id="hjallelse" shape="poly" coords="475,459,477,489,535,482,539,461,551,458,548,434,556,431,556,372,493,380,469,347,467,340,457,338,448,322,431,315,414,324,409,330,425,347,427,380,451,380,467,391,475,402,471,416,465,424,459,428,457,439,467,450" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lighthjallelse').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade4').style.display='block'" ;="" target="">


 <area id="tarup" shape="poly" coords="258,183,268,182,291,181,316,162,332,174,348,186,358,200,366,211,362,224,342,223,336,230,331,238,321,242,316,255,274,258,270,264,266,279,255,274,252,268,263,258,266,240,270,226,255,220,239,214,238,204,246,186" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lighttarup').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadetarup').style.display='block'" ;="">


 <area id="scthans" shape="poly" coords="460,142,426,156,406,170,405,189,410,213,420,224,426,230,423,240,432,246,442,240,452,247,470,245,476,242,473,214,468,192,460,184,476,171,461,158" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightscthans').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadescthans').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="vollsmosse" shape="poly" coords="480,170,496,170,500,182,500,195,507,205,524,216,524,232,516,241,502,242,502,236,493,233,484,237,478,225,474,196,469,186" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightvollsmose').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade19').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="sanderum" shape="poly" coords="249,292,262,291,271,286,294,284,306,287,311,302,335,293,351,286,364,290,378,298,396,310,406,327,398,336,404,345,388,357,377,353,372,341,370,328,350,331,325,333,306,330,290,318,275,308,262,299" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightsanderum').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade11').style.display='block'" ;="">

 <area id="hunderup" shape="poly" coords="366,285,375,275,396,263,408,277,425,276,427,265,437,263,446,269,442,274,449,285,438,286,440,304,434,306,431,288,422,289,418,308,413,316,408,322,396,303,390,296,378,294" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lighthunderup').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade22').style.display='block'" ;="">


  <area id="rosengaard" shape="poly" coords="415,320,422,309,425,294,430,294,430,305,431,309,443,306,444,290,454,287,448,275,452,267,441,260,434,260,431,251,440,246,450,249,461,250,475,248,480,241,490,242,500,244,510,247,522,248,523,259,532,263,551,266,567,268,562,287,555,300,535,306,528,311,522,317,507,301,493,295,447,309,444,314,434,311" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightrosengaard').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade8').style.display='block'" ;"="">


</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the full URL: `http://www.ssp-odense.dk/`

not just: `www.ssp-odense.dk`